# Delete first row and place copy of row on end of table

Tags: mysql

Hi guys I have a mySQL database with a table called queue the rows consist columns singer and song.  I'm using the table to keep the order the singers have gone up there is an auto increment Id

What I am trying to find is the proper syntax to copy the first row from my table to the last row with a new auto increment ID value and then delete the first row. It didn't seem such a challenge until I tried to write it . Any ideas are welcome.

Since getting an answer I have tried this.. but keep getting error 1111

```
 UPDATE `queue`
 SET `id` = MAX(id) + 1;
 WHERE `id` = MIN(id);
```

Have also tried this...how can this be so hard.

```
 Set $max = (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM queue);
 Set $min = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM queue);
 UPDATE `queue`
 SET `id` =  $max
 WHERE `id` = $min;
```

So I have abandoned the max() min() thought unless someone has a usable answer and moved to my original thought and I am very close. but my problem is I will not know the lowest id to remove because it would only be 1 once so I need to fill it in with a MIN(id) value or variable somehow.  Here is where I am at.

```
  INSERT INTO queue (SELECT NULL,singer, song1 FROM queue WHERE id = 1);
  DELETE FROM queue ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Mysql is not php, $ does not mark a variable. @ does.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `UPDATE` the row to change its `id` by using a `SET` and `WHERE` clause?

```
UPDATE `queue`
SET `id` = 21 -- (current_highest_value + 1)
WHERE `id` = 1
```

This way you don't have to worry about adding a new row and deleting the old one.

Comment: Very interesting thought going to look into that now.. need to research getting highest id value...thanks for the tip will try.  Also not sure how to work it for the second time around where the lowest id would be 2...off to research ty

Comment: Ok very cool MIN() and MAX() functions going to see If I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

i think all things are fine just you need to update SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0 for delete statement, so you can try below way

```
  SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;  
  INSERT INTO queue (SELECT NULL,singer, song1 FROM queue WHERE id = 1);
  DELETE FROM queue ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
```